# HTML proper positioning for bottom without affecting children

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a text with a tooltip in the box. I cannot change the properties of the box itself, but I would like to make it so that the tooltip is above the text. Here is what I have now:

```css
.tt-container .tooltiptext {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #1a7bc9;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    width: 300px;
    /*bottom: 100%;*/
}
.tt-container:hover .tooltiptext {
    display: block;
}
.tt-container {
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline;
}
.box {
    /*I cannot make changes to this*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><br><br>
    <div class="tt-container">
        <span class="tooltiptext">some more text which takes a bunch of space maan</span>
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

I think that the best way to achieve what I want would be doing `bottom: 100%` inside `tooltip-text`, but when I do so, the `bottom` is computed relative to the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the `tt-container`. I figure that this is because I have to use `position: relative` on the `tt-container`, but this will make it so that the tooltip is covered under the edge of the box. I have tried creating another `div` outside the `tt-container` with `position: relative`, but the result is the same and I don't know of any other ways. Is it possible to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

```css
    
.tt-container .tooltiptext {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    border-color: #1a7bc9;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    width: 300px;
   
}
.tt-container:hover .tooltiptext {
    display: block;
  
}
.tt-container {
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
}
.box {
    /*I cannot make changes to this*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><br><br>
    <div class="tt-container">
        <span class="tooltiptext">some more text which takes a bunch of space maan</span>
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

You should make the parent `position: relative` for `position:absolute` to know that it should be positioned relative to the parent.
It's not possible to make the tooltip go out of the box, because it has `overflow: auto;`.

Comment: Well, I have done it in my example :) I understand that it may not be possible by using `bottom`, but I am open for suggestions. I had some promising results using negative `margin-top`, but the problem is that whenever you change the layout or the text size it messes up and becomes either too large or too small...

Comment: Parent covering the text in not caused by ```bottom:100%```. Overflow auto prevents anything inside the box from getting out of it. You can't do both at the same time. Why can't you change the box div?

Comment: Again, it is not important to use `bottom`, this is just the solution that I thought of. The reason why I can't change the box is because in actuality it is only one of the usecases for this class, it is also present in the table and it will be messed up if I did this.

Comment: Can't you just use different classes? Or maybe add a class to the box that removes ```overflow: auto;``` by setting ```overflow: visible;```. Let me know if it works, if not - post more code.